# how can I specify linker flags just fort a specific lib in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake file like this for a single test.cpp file:

```
if (TARGET SMS++::UCBlock AND
    TARGET SMS++::MILPSolver)

    add_executable(TUDPS_test test.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(TUDPS_test PRIVATE
                          SMS++::MILPSolver
                          SMS++::UCBlock)

    add_test(NAME TUDPS_test
             COMMAND TUDPS_test
             WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif ()
```

and I want to specify:

```
"-Wl,--whole-archive,--allow-multiple-definition"
```

just for SMS++::MILPSolver, but not for SMS++::UCBlock or other deps that in the future will be added. So I make:

```
target_link_options(SMS++::MILPSolver "-Wl,--whole-archive,--allow-multiple-definition")
```

but I obtain:

```
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:14 (target_link_options):
  target_link_options can not be used on an ALIAS target.
```

beacuse in the CMakeLists.txt of the MILPSolver I have:

```
# This alias is defined so that executables in this same project can use
# the library with this notation.
add_library(${modNamespace}::${modName} ALIAS ${modName})
```

Should I add this here or in the CMakeLists of the submodule SMS++::MILPSolver?

Comment: `target_link_options`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I updated the question with new details :)

Comment: If you want to link `TUDPS_test` with those flags then call `target_link_options(TUDPS_test ...)`. Why are you calling it for `SMS++::MILPSolver`?